# Bukkit / Spigot API: Mapping damager and Victim

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to add the **damager name** as a key, and the **victim name** as the value, into my hashmap that's called *damageCheck*. This is all done in the `EntityDamageByEntityEvent`. However, when I try to store both the victim and damager, it all goes wrong.

Code:

```
    private HashMap<String, String> damageCheck = new HashMap<String, String>();

@EventHandler
public void onEntityDamageByEntityEvent(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {

    if(event.getEntity() instanceof Player || event.getDamager() instanceof Player) {
        Player victim = (Player) event.getEntity();
        Player damager = (Player) event.getDamager();

        String victimName = victim.getDisplayName(); // getting the victim name
        String damagerName = damager.getDisplayName(); // getting the damager name

        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("");
        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(victim.getDisplayName() + " is the victim!");
        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(damager.getDisplayName() + " is the damager!");
        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("");

        try {
            if(!damageCheck.containsKey(damagerName)) {
                damageCheck.put(victimName, damagerName);

                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("");
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(damageCheck.get(victimName) + " is victim!");
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(damageCheck.get(damagerName) + " is damager!");
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("");
            } else if(damageCheck.containsKey(damagerName)) {
                damageCheck.replace(damagerName, damagerName, damagerName);

                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("");
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(damageCheck.get(victimName) + " is victim!");
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(damageCheck.get(damagerName) + " is damager!");
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("");
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // do nothing lol
        }

    } else {
        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("There is no entity or damager!");
    }
}
```

[image]

First message was correct. *GetSparked* is the victim and *Fendyk* is the damager. But in the second message when trying to get the names out of the hashmap it output's wrong values.

**EDIT**: I'v changed 
*damageCheck.put(victimName, damagerName);*
to
*damageCheck.put(damagerName, victimName);*

But it now gives victim **null** (the first time hitting), why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i was testing out a complete new way of doing this, since i didn't really understand what you were referring to, anyways this is the code, that i think is what you really need

No need for the ***`new HashMap  <String, String>`***

```
private HashMap<String, String> damageCheck = new HashMap<>();
```

Code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onEntityDamageByEntityEvent(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {

    if(!(event.getDamager() instanceof Player) || !(event.getEntity() instanceof Player) ) return;

    String damagerName = event.getDamager().getName();
    String victimName = event.getEntity().getName();

    damageCheck.put(victimName, damagerName);

    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "" + ChatColor.STRIKETHROUGH + "-------------[ X ]-------------");
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + damagerName + ChatColor.GRAY + " is the damager");
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + victimName + ChatColor.GRAY + " is the victim");
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "" + ChatColor.STRIKETHROUGH + "-------------[ X ]-------------");

    Bukkit.getLogger().info(damageCheck.toString());

}
```

Removing entity data from the hashmap *though it's not accurate sometimes*

```
@EventHandler
public void onEntityDeathEvent(EntityDeathEvent event){
    damageCheck.remove(event.getEntity().getName());
    damageCheck.remove(event.getEntity().getKiller().getName());
}
```

You can remove the check for players only, it'll work on any entity
 *Just remove*

`if(!(event.getDamager() instanceof Player) || !(event.getEntity() instanceof Player) ) return;`

Comment: Thank you very much for your information and help. I really appreciate that.